# custom user table columns

Tags: columns

I'm doing this, which according to all of the documentation I've read, should override every column value in my manage users table. For some reason it's not working in WP 4.1. Any insight appreciated.

```
function retro_custom_users_table_content($value, $column_name, $user_id){
    $value = "hi";
    return $value;
}
add_filter('manage_users_custom_column','retro_custom_users_table_content', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter is only applied to custom columns that are added by you (or plugins and themes), not the default columns. If you want to modify the output of all default columns, I think you may have to add your own columns and duplicate the functionality of the defaults, then unset the defaults via `manage_users_columns`, since not all of them have filters to let you modify the values. When in doubt, dig into the source code and do a search for the filter to see it in context.

Comment: Sounds good. How can I change column order to move my newly created column to the beginning of the table?

Comment: see [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/8431/4771). you basically have to build a new array with the order you want and return that back.

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much. I've got it all working now.